# Basic Understanding of Class inheritance with QPushbutton / QWidget in PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, oop, pyqt4

it's a Problem of basic OOP understanding i guess. but: Instead of

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------

        """
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        ...
```

I want my customized Button, inherited like:

```
class MyButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

So, i can use it instead:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------

        """
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        button = MyButton(self)
        ...
```

The Problem is, that i don't know how i can make the button being an Object of the Widget, since i can't pass in the widget itself? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Suggested reading: [Python classes and object oriented programming](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/)

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs/3394902#3394902, may probably helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both case do the same thing: you create `button`, an instance of a class, in the `__init__` function of `MyWidget`.

Problem is, you won't be able to use `button` in any other function, because it fell out of scope. You didn't define it as a class attribute, you only defined it as a local variable for this particular function.
To have `button` as an attribute of `MyWidget`, you have to use the keyword `self`:

```
self.button=MyButton()
```

Then later on you will be able to do something like `myWidget.button.someFunction..`. You'll also be able to call `self.button` in any other method of `MyWidget`.

---

Some of you confusion might comes from PyQt.

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
```

With the code above, you're passing as an argument `self` (in your case, `self` refers to `myWidget`). This is really specific to Qt, and the purpose is to set `myWidget` as the parent of `button`.

`self.button =  QtGui.QPushButton(self)` can seem redundant, but the first `self` is for python, and the second for Qt (which is C++).

---

Finally, you should subclass with a parent parameter:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(parent)
```

Comment: i think i didn't get quite to the point, which is: i want the button to be shown in the widget. Works with QPushbutton Object but not with the customized QPushbutton, since the passed in "self" is missing. I could fix this by adding *args to MyButton's init. But thanks anyway

Comment: If you subclass as I showed, you can pass `self` as an argument. Also, you could try to use layout, it will attribute a parent to widgets automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Works like this:

```
class MyPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
```

To really understand this i probably would find the answer in PyQt reference

Comment: its not about args and kwargs but more how Qt Objects handle an object self being passed in as argument with *args. but thanks anyway